# Add an array item or merge two yaml files

Tags: jenkins, yaml, sonarqube, yq

This is file-a.yaml

```
unclassified:
  sonarGlobalConfiguration:
    buildWrapperEnabled: false
    installations:
      - credentialsId: "ID1"
        name: "sonarqube"
        serverUrl: "https://example.com"
        triggers:
          skipScmCause: false
          skipUpstreamCause: false
      - credentialsId: "ID2"
        name: "sonarqube-2"
        serverUrl: "https://example.co.uk"
        triggers:
          skipScmCause: false
          skipUpstreamCause: false
```

This is file-b.yaml

```
unclassified:
  sonarGlobalConfiguration:
    installations:
      - credentialsId: "ID-3"
        name: "sonarqube-3"
        serverUrl: "https://example.org"
        triggers:
          skipScmCause: false
          skipUpstreamCause: false
```

I would like to merge the two files so file-a.yaml contains 3 items under unclassified.sonarGlobalConfiguration.installations

Either merge the two files or just add a new item to the installation array. Can this be done with YQ?

I tried a few combinations of YQ commands however failed terribly - has someone done this type of thing before and give any suggestions?

Comment: FYI: what is probably called an array and its items in some programming language you use, is called a sequence resp. its entries in a YAML document.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest `yq` (`v4.34.2`):

```bash
$ yq ea '. as $item ireduce ({}; . *+ $item )' file-a.yaml file-b.yaml
unclassified:
  sonarGlobalConfiguration:
    buildWrapperEnabled: false
    installations:
      - credentialsId: "ID1"
        name: "sonarqube"
        serverUrl: "https://example.com"
        triggers:
          skipScmCause: false
          skipUpstreamCause: false
      - credentialsId: "ID2"
        name: "sonarqube-2"
        serverUrl: "https://example.co.uk"
        triggers:
          skipScmCause: false
          skipUpstreamCause: false
      - credentialsId: "ID-3"
        name: "sonarqube-3"
        serverUrl: "https://example.org"
        triggers:
          skipScmCause: false
          skipUpstreamCause: false
```